# ember.js controller properties

Tags: ember.js

i'm trying to set a property of a controller

Trying to do so

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="App.tastingsController.names"}}
```

it does not work

```
App.tastingsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  names: ["Velato", "Abbastanza limpido", "Limpido", "Cristallino", "Brillante"]
```

while this version is working correctly (but gives this warning:`WARNING: The immediate parent route did not render into the main outlet and the default 'into' option may not be expected` )

```
App.tastingsController.names = ["Velato", "Abbastanza limpido", "Limpido", "Cristallino", "Brillante"]
```

here's my routes:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route "home", { path: "/" }
  @route "about"
  @resource "tastings", ->
    @route "new"
    @resource "tasting", { path: ":tasting_id"}
```

Can you explain me why?

( found it [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html))

thank you

Marco

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

- `App.tastingsController` should be named `App.TastingsController`.  Controller Classes should begin with a capital letter.
- You are getting a warning because you skipped a template within the route hierarchy.  I need more information on the routes to help fix this.
- If you need to set a property on the controller (such as `names` in your case), there are two ways to do it:

  Either set it in the route:

  ```
  App.TastingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set('names', names: ['list', 'of', 'names']);
    }
  });
  ```

  Or you can set it directly when defining the controller class:

  ```
  App.TastingsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [],
    names: ['list', 'of', 'names']
  });
  ```
- When you need to reference a controller from the view/template, don't name the entire controller class. Just use the property you want to bind to (assuming your view's controller is `App.TastingsController`)

`{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="names"}}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: updated with the route.

trying the controller option, it gives me: `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'length' on an undefined object.`

Comment: It depends in which template you are using the select.  If in the `tastings` template, then put the names in `App.TastingsController`, if you're using it in the `tastings/new` template, then it should be in the `App.TastingsNewController`.

Comment: After seeing the routes, I can guess that you are getting the `WARNING` because you skipped defining the `tastings` template, just add this: `<script type="text/x-handlebars id="tastings">{{outlet}}</script>` and the warning should go away.